# Find lower bound of function ？

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

Can someone help me find a lower bound to the function

$$\ln(1 - 0.5^u),  u\ge0$$

I tried to use the Taylor formula, but it didn't seem to work. I would be grateful if anyone could give me some advice.

Comment: I guess you wanted to write $u>0$, as the expression is not defined at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

As $u\rightarrow 0$, the expression tends to $-\infty$, so there is no lower bound.

Comment: Thank for your reply. if $u>=1$?

Comment: The function is clerly strictly monotone increasing. So in that case, the minimum is $f(1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I want to get a lower bound function, not to get minimum. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: You asked lower bound. I also don't understand the difference. $f(1)=\ln 0.5 \approx -0.7$ is a global lower bound. If you want, this can be rephrased as: the constant $-0.7$ function is below $f$ everywhere.

Comment: yeah, constant $-0.7$ is ok, but it is a constant function. I want to get a non constant function.

Answer (score 2):

As a general approach you could try to find a minimum point.

$$y=\ln(1-0.5^u).$$

Differentiating,

$$y'=\frac{\log(2)0.5^u}{1-u^{0.5}}.$$

To find stationary points, set equal to zero to obtain

$$0.5^u=0,$$

which has no solutions, so there are no stationary points. Hence, no minimum and so no lower bound.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  but my purpose is to get a lower bound function, not to get  minimum.

Comment: $f(u)=c$ where $c$ is constant is a lower bound function. Maybe you mean a non  constant function..

Comment: You just keep changing the problem. Be decisive. Also, what purpose would such an answer serve? I can easlily give you a linear lower bound (why is that any better than a constant lower bound, which was your original problem, is beyond me, though), but then you will say you really want to get a non-constant functionwhose value at 7.63 is 4.12 and that is not continuous at $\pi$. What is the motivation of the problem, and what is the answer you are really looking for? As soon as you can answer these questions, maybe others will help you. Also, I do not see any of your own efforts.